# Existence of reduced norms for CSAs using fpqc descent

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field and $A$ be a central simple algebra over $k$. It's known that $A$ has a splitting field (i.e. a field $K/k$ such that $A_K\cong M_n(K)$ for some $n$) which is finite and Galois.

This allows us to define a *reduced norm* $N:A\to k$ which is given by the determinant $M_n(K)\to K$ and then descended (via Galois descent) to $k$.

I wonder if we can do the same thing using fpqc descent but avoiding the need for the existence of a finite Galois splitting field, and using only that $\overline{k}$ splits $A$, which is way simpler. (Of course that's not for didactic reasons, since we're exchanging a hard theorem for a harder one. That's just for my curiosity.)

Comment: A finite index subgroup of $\operatorname{Gal}(\bar k/k)$ fixes $A_{\bar k}$, what else can be said?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე The way I understood the question, it's about the difference between separable and algebraic closure, not about finiteness of the splitting field extension.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger precisely! The finiteness is very simple (an isomorphism $A_{\bar{k})\cong M_n(\bar{k})$ involves only a finite amount of data, so we can find a finite extension which does the job). The hard part is proving the existence of a separable splitting field.

Comment: You can define the reduced norm using fpqc descent. Have a look at chapter III, section 1.2 in Knus' "Quadratic and Hermitian Forms over Rings", for instance.

Comment: @UriyaFirst This solves my question. Thank you. If you would like to turn this into an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: @Gabriel Very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the reduced norm using fpqc descent. Have a look at chapter III, section 1.2 in Knus' "[Quadratic and Hermitian Forms over Rings](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-75401-2)", for instance.

Comment: Thank you for this reference!  The [review](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1096299) mentions that this is a relatively young theory, with few books; but Knus's book also is over 30 years old.  Is it still the best reference for someone trying to learn the subject, or are there more modern references?

Comment: @LSpice If you want quadratic forms over *rings*, then Knus' book is still the best source in my opinion, although the notation has shifted a little since the book was written. There is also a much-shorter-by-comparison monograph by Paul Balmer titled "Witt groups" which gives (tersely) even more modern flavors of the theory of quadratic forms over schemes. Both texts are somewhat advanced, however. Over *fields*, the most modern reference I am aware of is Elman, Karpenko and Merkurjev's book on the subject: "The Algebraic and Geometric Theory of Quadratic Forms".

Comment: @LSpice Continuation of my comment: Scharlau's book "Quadratic and Hermitian Forms" is a little older than Knus' book, focuses mainly on the field case, but is more elementary, and may be better suited as a first read on quadratic forms. It also has a lot of material on local and global fields (if that is your focus), and Chapter 7 in that book may serve as a neat introduction to hermitian forms over rings with involution. Where to start really depends on one's background and goals (and might be the topic of an MO question?).

Comment: @‍UriyaFirst, thank you very much!  I did not know about the Balmer or EKM book.  I am somewhat familiar with Scharlau's book (though I find the treatment of Hermitian forms a bit befuddling), and was wondering where to go next.  I will see if I can form a well defined MO question some time.

Comment: [References](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414943/existence-of-reduced-norms-for-csas-using-fpqc-descent/415065#comment1064643_415065) from @‍UriyaFirst: [Balmer - Witt groups](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-27855-9_11); [Elman, Karpenko, and Merkurjev - The algebraic and geometric theory of quadratic forms](https://doi.org/10.1090/coll/056); [Scharlau - Quadratic and Hermitian forms](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-69971-9).